# readonly div in CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, readonly

I need to make 'read-only **div**' using with CSS or JavaScript or Jquery. Not only text-box and all. Full `div`. That div contain anything(image, ,other div,text-box,...)

That should support by all Browser.

Any idea?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could use `pointer-events: none;` to disable mouse DOM interaction (like click, hover, etc) on certain element. Example:

```css
div {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" value="value" />
    <br />
    <textarea>value</textarea>
</div>
```

However, even though `pointer-events: none;` is there, it's still possible to make the cursor to be focus on the element (or it's children). Meaning if we move the cursor focus on the `<input />` tag, then it's possible to edit the value.

Example: try to click the `<input />` tag, then press **tab** in keyboard, the cursor focus will be on input, making it editable.

---

To make `<input />` tag **completely un-editable**, put `readonly` attribute on the tag. Below is simple example to do it by using jQuery `.prop()`. You can also put the attribute directly on the tag, depending on the needs.

```js
$("input, textarea").prop("readonly", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="value" />
  <br />
  <textarea>value</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: are you use this option to div?

Comment: This is a bit of a hack that doesn't really work. The tags are not readonly as you can tab to them and edit to your hearts desire. Plus `pointer-events` is relatively new and not widely supported.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this with CSS unfortunately, you're after the `readonly` attribute on HTML elements. You can pretty easily accomplish what you want using JavaScript, here's an example with jQuery.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUng2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="readonly">
    <input type="text" />
    <div><input type="checkbox" /> Blah</div>
    <textarea>abc</textarea>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.readonly').find('input, textarea, select').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

Comment: `<a>` tags and `<div>` tags are read-only, do you mean stopping all interaction?

Comment: yes, all things... if include Javascript action means, it's too too good.

Comment: Typically this is done by overlaying a `<div>` over everything so that click events don't pass through. The same thing can be achieved using Noval's `pointer-events:none;` in combination with this `readonly` attribute solution. I believe the user will still be able to tab to `<a>` tags though.

Answer (score 3):

**Just Try With The Following :**

***Script Part :***

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#previewDiv :input").attr("disabled", true); 
});
</script>
```

***HTML Part :***

```
<div id="previewDiv">
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="test" value="test">
</div>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid, you can't control elements behavior with CSS.

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets - it's only for styling elements.

---

But you can use `JavaScript`.

Untested `jQuery` example above:

```
$('#myDiv').children().attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").prop("readonly", true);

<div> 
    <input type="text" value="value" /> <br />
    <textarea>value</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('div *').prop('disabled',true);

Comment: Please also add the explanation for your answer so that future readers get the idea of how and why your solution worked.